# Webpage not available on android web app

Tags: java, android, web, html

I'm developing a web based app for android. If there is no connection, the standard: "Webpage not available" is posted. But i need a page that i have designed before and saved it in the app, to be shown. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You'll have to implement the network connection check yourself, and then if it's not connected, show a local resource (i.e. not_available.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should check for internet connection. In case that there is no network available you load your html file.

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
if(!isNetworkAvailable)
{
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/FILENAME.html");
}
```